# Relation between open and closed sets in Metric space

Tags: general-topology

let $(\mathbb{N},d)$, where $d : \mathbb{N} \times \ \mathbb{N} \to \mathbb{R}$, $d(m,n)=| \frac{1}{n}-\frac{1}{m}| $. Is every open set closed at the same time? Find $Bd(\{n \in \mathbb{N} : n \ge 3\})$.

Any ideas?

Comment: ..what is $N$??

Comment: Is Bd meant to be the boundary?

Comment: Bd is boundary and $N$ is natural

Comment: Isn't $d(m,n)\ge\left\lvert\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right\rvert>0$ for all $m\ne n$?

Comment: So what is the $\left(\frac1n-\frac1{n+1}\right)$-neighbourhood of $\frac1n$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each point is isolated, hence for all $n$, the set $\{n\}$  is open and closed.
Hence any set is open, and so any set is also closed.

Hence the closure of $A= \{n | n \ge 3\}$ is $A$ and the closure of $A^c$ is $A^c$. Hence the boundary is empty.